# Enable/Disable input - knockout

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, input, knockout.js

I would like to make my form editable after I'll click button.

I write code for a button click but I don't how to change state of the inputs in a form.

```
viewModel.test= function () {
   //code here
}
<input type="text"/> // Enable/Disable this
```

Can I disable/enable all inputs in the form or I just need to do it one by one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With pure knockout you can do this, basically toggling the `isDisabled` observable which updates the `disabled` attribute on the bound element.  You can use knockout `attr` binding to set attributes on elements.

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.isDisabled = ko.observable(false);
    this.disable = function(){
        self.isDisabled(true);
    }
    this.enable = function(){
         self.isDisabled(false);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); 


<div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="attr : {'disabled' : isDisabled}"/> // Sets disabled attribute if isDisabled is true.
    <input type="text" data-bind="attr : {'disabled' : isDisabled}"/>
    <button data-bind="click : disable">Disable</button>
    <button data-bind="click : enable">Enable</button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xggu9Lv2/2/

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do it by jQuery, but I rather would like to use Knockout

Comment: The above will work, but it is actually not necessary to use the `attr` data-binding since knockout provides a `disable` and an `enable` data-binding as shown in @Wahwahwah's answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how well this is supported in IE8 and under but, you can use knockout to enable / disable form inputs:

```js
function vm() {
  var self = this;
  self.hasForm = ko.observable(false);
  self.cellphoneNumber = "";
  self.personName = ""
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type='checkbox' data-bind="checked: hasForm" />I have a cellphone & a name
</p>
<p>
  <form id="form">
    <label>Your cellphone number:</label>
    <input type='text' data-bind="value: cellphoneNumber, enable: hasForm" />
    <label>Your Name:</label>
    <input type='text' data-bind="value: personName, enable: hasForm" />
  </form>

</p>
```

...Based on the [ko documentation on "enable."](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html)